# Two planets undertake uniform circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

Two planets undertake uniform circular motion around a star. For the two planets, the mass, speed and distance from the star's centre is respectively $m$, $v$, $r$ and $m'$, $v'$, $r'$. If $r'=4r$, the ratio $T'/T$ of the periods of revolution of the planets is? The answer is 8 however I am not sure which formula to use because the ones I have used do not give me that answer.

Comment: Have you heard of a technique known as "ratio and proportion?" Learn to use that. It's useful in a myriad of situations. *Also* Don't be a formula hunter. Be a concept learner.

Answer (score 1):

To solve these kinds of problems I see at least two equivalent approaches:

- you can study this as circular motion, then making the centripetal force equal to the gravitational attraction and find the periods as functions of the two rays;
- conceptually, the laws of Kepler apply to this situation. The third law is perfect for this problem.

Comment: Don't simply throw around an equation. IF you're going to answer a homework question, you should give a conceptual explanation.

Comment: Tried to make it conceptual